# Try Catch C# How Do I do it?

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

im working on a assignment where I now have to implement the Try & Catch-method too catch inputs other than numbers in my program. I understand the process and explanations in my study-book and have also done some minor examples while trying it out. But when I want to implement this into my assignment I am getting stuck. Can someone please explain to me in a manor as to not spoil anything but try and help me along the way?

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace BastunKP
{
  class Program
  {
       public static double FahrToCels(double fahr)
       {
          return (fahr - 32) * 5 / 9;
       }

       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Skriv in Fahrenheit: ");
          double fahr = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
          double tempCels = FahrToCels(fahr);

          do            
          {      
            try               
            {
                //Dont know what to write here.
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Du kan bara skriva in siffor, testa igen.");
            }

            if (tempCels < 73)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är för kallt, skruva upp lite!");
            }
            else if (tempCels > 77)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är för varmt, skruva ner lite!");
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är nu bra, hoppa in!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            fahr = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            tempCels = FahrToCels(fahr);              
          }        
          while (tempCels < 73 || tempCels > 77);
          return;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `//Dont know what to write here.` Whatever the code is that _might_ throw an exception. _Think about the code you were planning to write before you added the `try..catch` in there. That is the code you should put inside the `try` block._

Comment: First I thought that I had to have the code "double fahr = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());" in there but that does not work..

Comment: declare your variable outside the try. Inside, just assign the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, lets write code without any exception handling. Get the basics right first. We need a method that:

1. Asks the user for a temperature in Fahrenheit.
2. If the input is not a valid `double`, go to 1.
3. Convert the value to Celsius.
4. If not, go to 1.
5. If the temperature in Celsius does not belong to `(73, 77)` go to 1.

   ```
   public static double GetTemperatureFromUser()
   {
        while (true)
        {
             Console.Write("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
             var t = FahrToCels(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));

             if (t < 73)
             {
                 Console.Write("Temperature is too low. Try again.");
             }
             else if (t > 77)
             {
                 Console.Write("Temperature is too high. Try again.");
             }
             else
             {
                 return t;
             }
        }
   }
   ```

Ok, that looks good. Now let's add some exception handling. First question: what can go wrong here and throw an exception?

```
var t = FahrToCels(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));
```

seems like a likely suspect. Is there anything else that can throw? Hmmm, no.

Ok, second question: what code shouldn't be executing if `ToDouble()` throws? Well, anything that depends on the result of `ToDouble()` obviously. So all that code also goes in the `try` block.

Ok, third question: what code should run if `ToDouble()` throws? In our case we should inform the user that the input was not a valid `double`. Ok, that code needs to go in `catch` block.

Think of `try-catch` as a fancy `if` that controls the execution path of your code: if the code throws, go to `catch` if not, keep executing normally inside the `try` block.

Fourth question: what code should run after everything else inside the `try` or `catch` blocks no matter what happens? In your case nothing, but if there were, it would go in the `finally` block.

Note that `catch` and `finally` blocks are not mandatory. The only rule is that at least one of them must be present immediately following a `try` block; `try-catch`, `try-finally` and `try-catch-finally` are all valid.

Fifth and last: what exceptions do you want to handle? You should always handle *only the exceptions that you know how to handle* and ignore all others. What exceptions can `ToDouble` throw? If you read the documentation you'll see it can throw `FormatException` and `OverflowException`. You can handle both because they amount to the same thing: and invalid user input.

Ok, lets rewrite our method:

Does the `while` loop depend on whatever happens in `ToDouble`? No, the method should be running in a loop no matter what happens inside; the only way to exit the loop is when the user inputs a valid number and the method returns. Ok then, the `while` block goes outside any exception handling and so does the user prompt:

```
public static double GetTemperatureFromUser()
{
     while (true)
     {
         Console.Write("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
         //...
     }
}
```

And now the next instruction is our primary suspect, so it obviously must go inside the `try` block. Everything else we've written in our method depends on the value of `t` so we put all that also inside the `try` block:

```
public static double GetTemperatureFromUser()
{
     while (true)
     {
          Console.Write("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");

          try
          {
              var t = FahrToCels(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));

              if (t < 73)
              {
                  Console.Write("Temperature is too low. Try again.");
              }
              else if (t > 77)
              {
                  Console.Write("Temperature is too high. Try again.");
              }
              else
              {
                  return t;
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Ok, now we're only missing the `catch` block. We'll add one for each exception we know how to handle:

```
public static double GetTemperatureFromUser()
{
     while (true)
     {
          Console.Write("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");

          try
          {
              var t = FahrToCels(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));

              if (t < 73)
              {
                  Console.Write("Temperature is too low. Try again.");
              }
              else if (t > 77)
              {
                  Console.Write("Temperature is too high. Try again.");
              }
              else
              {
                  return t;
              }
         }
         catch (FormatException)
         {
              Console.Write("Invalid number format. Try again.");
         }
         catch (OverflowException)
         {
              Console.Write("Number is too large or too small. Try again.");
         }
     }
}
```

And there you go, we're done.

Comment: Thank you! This made the code work! One question though, where do you get the names "FormatException" and "OverflowException" from in the catch parameters?

Comment: @Kian First of all, this answer is not meant to "make the code work", its meant to make you start understanding how exception handling works in c#. Simply making your code work would have required a much shorter answer. Second, `System.FormatException` and `System.OverflowException` are classes implemented in the framework that extend `System.Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no required `try/catch` to check valid input. You could use `double.TryParse`;

```
Console.WriteLine("Skriv in Fahrenheit: ");
double fahr;
double tempCels;
bool isInputCorrect = false;
while (!isInputCorrect)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!double.TryParse(input, out fahr))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Du kan bara skriva in siffor, testa igen.");
        continue;
    }
    tempCels = FahrToCels(fahr);
    if (tempCels < 73)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är för kallt, skruva upp lite!");
        continue;
    }
    else if (tempCels > 77)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är för varmt, skruva ner lite!");
        continue;
    }
    isInputCorrect = true;
}
Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är nu bra, hoppa in! tempCels : " + tempCels);
Console.ReadKey();
```

If you insist to use `try/catch`, you could try like this;

Just replace `double.TryParse` part.

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
try
{
    fahr = Convert.ToDouble(input);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Du kan bara skriva in siffor, testa igen.");
    continue;
}
```