# What does it mean to validate within the set method/property?

Tags: c#

I am currently doing a project for school, and to get full marks you must;

- More able candidates should use validation within the field Set method/Property of a class and throw back error messages where relevant. It is expected that a validation process calls methods from a static class.

Could someone please explain what the exam board mean by this?

Also,

- More able candidates should be encouraged to make good use of try catch, get/set, and the use of specific or custom exceptions.

I've been doing validation like this:

```
if (isValidString(txtUsername.Text, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$") && (txtPassword.Text.Length > 5))
```

Does that mean I need to change something?

EDIT:

So, if I put my validation in the set method, will that tick this off?

```
It is expected that a validation process calls methods from a static class.
```

or is that something else?

Comment: For your validation, they want you to use try-catch. Please read the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47992265/7977464

Comment: Write code without validation first. Then imagine that can go wrong (out of memory, disk space, overflow, not enough right, etc), and write it into try-catch clause.

Answer (score 0):

> More able candidates should use validation within the field Set method/Property of a class and throw back error messages where relevant. It is expected that a validation process calls methods from a static class.

I won't give you a code sample just so you figure out by yourself, however, a property (like `public string Name { get; set: }`) can have logic if you use a backing field.

For example:

```
public class Student
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

What they are asking you is to validate whatever is assigned to the property `set` method, instead of validating the input and then assigning it to the property.

> More able candidates should be encouraged to make good use of try catch, get/set, and the use of specific or custom exceptions.

This overlaps somewhat with what I showed above. However, they are also asking you to throw specific/custom exceptions rather than general ones.
A basic example:

```
public void AssignName(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        //WRONG!!!
        // Exception is the base class, this doesn't provide you anything meaningful 
        throw new Exception("name is null!!!);

        //Correct:
        // ArgumentNullException tells you that a null value was passed when this isn't valid
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    }
}
```